# Which sites don't participate in Winter Bash?

Tags: support, stack-exchange, winter-bash

Which Q&A sites in the Stack Exchange network don't participate in [Winter Bash](https://winterbash2018.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: Not Q&A is? [SEDE](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/120907/highest-view-rate-questions-non-community-wiki-4) and [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/5169/history/18019#18019)?

Comment: I don't consider those as Q&A sites (Area 51 is only Q, but some hats could work), but that's just my personal opinion.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following Q&A sites don't participate in Winter Bash. They can be recognized by not having the snowflake in the top bar, and the fact that they don't appear in the [Winter Bash leaderboard](https://winterbash2018.stackexchange.com/leaderboard).

- [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net) – they have never participated at all since they were migrated to Stack Exchange 2.0 in 2013, according to [this Meta post](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/a/2054/70594).
- [CS50](https://cs50.stackexchange.com) - this is in several aspects (e.g. privilege levels) a private beta, and private betas don't participate in Winter Bash.
- The sites hosted by Stack Overflow for Teams don't participate [in order to keep activity there private](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/319997/295232).

---

Data from earlier editions of Winter Bash is incomplete, but it is known that sites that were in private beta at the time a specific Winter Bash started didn't participate in Winter Bash that year.

Comment: I'd remove CS50, it's not really part of SE network, just some failed experiment that they still keep anyway. As for the other two, MO mods probably said "no" when asked by SE staff (no public meta post, and all four active mods have no hats on other sites, most likely they personally dislike this), and Iota is likely "too new", and doesn't even have mods yet.

Comment: CS50 doesn't show up on the list of [sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites#traffic) but it does show up on the list of [accounts](https://stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=accounts) (if you happen to have one). It *is* a Q&A site (unlike Area 51), that's why I have included it.

Comment: OK, fair enough. Found [this better, and official, proof of MO not taking part in WB](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/a/3068/36102) though. :)

Comment: Here's the thing I don't understand. MathOverflow has questions like [What are some examples of colorful language in serious mathematics papers?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/22299) but they don't participate in Winter Bash because "some of our esteemed users [...] do not come here for silly fun". Seriously? I really don't understand graduate level math but even I know this doesn't add up. :P

Comment: @Laurel because while programmers look for consistency, mathematicians look for proof.

Comment: Those MathOverflow people... Can't have any fun....

Comment: @Laurel Just caught wind of this thread. I think the general feeling has been pretty well summed up by Asaf Karagila: "You don't have to be "a serious professor" to dislike these things. I enjoy plenty of nonsensical shenanigans, but not this sort of "funtime activity". And please stop writing "hatz". 1337z0r sp33k ist ub3rk00l, amirite?"