# Do you earn hats for activity on private Teams?

Tags: support, winter-bash, stack-overflow-for-teams

A lot of the listed criteria do not make it clear whether or not activity on private teams will give you a hat.

A few examples I am not sure if teams would qualify or not:

> post a competing answer to an existing accepted answer, reaching a score of at least +3

or

> earn 150 reputation points on three different sites (not including Stack Overflow) within 15 days.

Or do teams posts just generally not count in any way?

Are there any guidelines for which types of things you might get credit for in a team or not?

Comment: /me proposes a new *Stack Overflow for Hats*.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No, Winter Bash is completely disabled in Stack Overflow for Teams. There are no hats and not even a snowflake in the top bar while you're on a private page.

Earning hats for activity on Teams is also out of the question. Our customers have an expectation of privacy, and even the fact that a user, say, earned a particular badge in a private Team (which would be publicly visible if they earned a hat for it) is something they can expect to remain private.

I should also note that even though it may feel like Stack Overflow activity, any data for Teams is stored in a completely different place that is not even accessible to the code that runs Winter Bash.