# How can I find the total number of times each website on Stack Exchange has participated on Winter Bash?

Tags: discussion, winter-bash

How can I find the total number of times each website on Stack Exchange has participated on Winter Bash? Is there a way to know this?

If it is difficult to find, Is there any way to find out the total number of times, these websites have participated in Winter Bash?

Stack Overflow, Arqade, Mathematics, Ask Ubuntu, English Language & Usage

Comment: Related: [Which sites don't participate in Winter Bash?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/305164/295232) Otherwise, I'd assume they participated if they were in public beta or graduated.

Comment: Do you need this data for something? It's actually hard to find a source of visits from WB 2020.

Comment: You can only find this by visiting all meta sites and find the posts that ask for whether they want to opt-in or not. I'm pretty sure no history is kept on file or available in a convenient format.

Comment: ... As far as I'm aware, for the years WB was network-wide, all sites other than MO participated.